# How to spawn process with arguments from erlang shell

Tags: erlang, spawn, erlang-shell

I do not know what overload of `spawn` to use when launching a process from the erlang shell , since i need to pass arguments.

```
A=spawn(
    fun(TID)-> 
           receive {FROM,MSG}->
                  FROM ! {self(),MSG}
           after 0 ->
                  TID !{self(),timeouted}
           end
   end,
   TID
  ).
```

There is no overload for just the `function` and arguments.
What is the module name when launching from shell ?

I have also tried:

```
A=spawn(?MODULE,fun()->....,TID).
```

**P.S**
In my case as you can see i need to provide arguments to the `spawn` method , while running it directly from the erlang shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you define a function in a module:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

go(X)-> 
    receive {From, Msg}->
        From ! {self(), Msg}
    after 0 ->
        io:format("~s~n", [X])
    end.
```

Then do this:

```
9> c(a).                         
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

10> Pid = spawn(a, go, ["hello"]).
hello
<0.95.0>
```

Defining functions in the shell is too much of a pain in the ass.

**Response to comment:**

Here's how you can do simple testing in erlang:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

do(Y) ->
    Y.

go(X)-> 
    receive {From, Msg}->
        From ! {self(), Msg}
    after 0 ->
        X
    end.

do_test() ->
    10 = do(10).
go_test() ->
    "hello" = go("hello").
```

In the shell:

```
1> c(a).

2> a:test().
  2 tests passed.
ok
```

Here's what happens when a test fails:

```
5> a:test().
a: go_test...*failed*
in function a:go_test/0 (a.erl, line 18)
**error:{badmatch,"hello"}
  output:<<"">>

=======================================================
  Failed: 1.  Skipped: 0.  Passed: 1.
error

6>
```

You don't even need to use eunit because you can simply do:

```
go_test() ->
    "hello" = go("hello").
```

Then in the shell:

```
1> c(a).
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported

2> a:go_test().
```

You'll get a bad match error if `go("hello")` doesn't return `"hello"`:

> ** exception error: no match of right hand side value "hello"
>        in function  a:go_test/0 (a.erl, line 18)

The advantage of using eunit is that with one command, `a:test()`, you can execute all the functions in the module that end in `_test`.

Comment: I know you can define in a module, but i wanted to do adhoc tests and was interested in spawning the process with arguments directly from shell.

Comment: *but i wanted to do adhoc tests*--Yeah but doing any typing in the shell is too much of a pain in the ass.  You can do add hoc tests in the module you are testing by typing the tests in the module.  See the bottom of my answer for an example.

Answer (score 4):

Just embed the definition in a fun:

```
A = fun(X) ->
    TID = X,             
    spawn(      
        fun()->  
            receive {FROM,MSG}->          
                FROM ! {self(),MSG}    
            after 0 ->                    
                TID !{self(),timeouted}
            end                           
        end                                  
    )
end.
```

and then you can use `A(YourParam)`.